# how to insert data into room and sequentially get id from tables to insert new data?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

How do I sequentially add data to the database?

I need to add two words to the "word" table , then get their rowid and add to the "word pair" table, then get the rowid of the "word pair" table and add to the "word base and word pairs" table

Here is my code inside fragmemnt:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    var languageId = vocabularyViewModel.getLanguageId(word.wordLanguage) // yet added to db 
    var languageId2 = vocabularyViewModel.getLanguageId(word.translatedLanguage) 
    languageId.combine(languageId2) { l1, l2 ->
        val r1 = vocabularyViewModel.addWord_(word.wordToTranslate, l1)
        val r2 = vocabularyViewModel.addWord_(word.translatedWord, l2)
        val r3 = vocabularyViewModel.addPairOfWords(r1.toInt(), r2.toInt())
        vocabularyViewModel.addWordBasePairOfWords(adapter.wordBaseName, r3.toInt())
}
```

Here is my code inside view model:

`

```
fun getLanguageId(language: String) = repo.getLanguageId(language)

suspend fun addWord_ (name: String, id: Int) =
        repo.insertWord(Word(name = name, languageId = id))

suspend fun addPairOfWords(wordId: Int, translateId: Int) =
            repo.insertPairOfWords(
                PairOfWords(word_id = wordId , translate_id = translateId)
            )

 fun addWordBasePairOfWords(wordBaseName: String, pairId: Int) =
        repo.getWordBaseId(wordBaseName).map {
            repo.insertWordBasePairOfWords(PairOfWordsWordBaseCrossRef(it, pairId))
        }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

you can make a dao instruction return (Long or Int) depend on your id type and store it in variable after done

Comment: yes, i'm trying to do this but can't understand how to process two flows in one launch for collecting from two stateflows Int value that will use for insert to table PairOfWords(wordId: Int, translateId: Int)